# Oracle on Docker :: ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle19c

I have to setup the **$ORACLE_SID** every time I login into **sqlplus** on Oracle Docker image.

> Steps to reproduce:

1. I login into a brand new 19c image freshly downloaded and installed from Oracle: `docker exec -it 19c bash`
2. I check **$ORACLE_SID** and the command `echo $ORACLE_SID` return me an empty line (very strange!?)
3. So I setup the **$ORACLE_SID** manually: `export ORACLE_SID="ORCLCDB"`
4. I check again the **$ORACLE_SID** and this time the command `echo $ORACLE_SID` returns me `ORCLCDB` which is the right name I setup
5. I exit from the bash Docker terminal with `exit`
6. I log back in `docker exec -it 19c bash`
7. I check if the **$ORACLE_SID** has been kept with `echo $ORACLE_SID` and it returns me an empty line again

[image]

Why the change is not permanent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the container is started, there's `no` way to change/add the environment variable. Therefore, the best option is to `stop and remove the existing container, then recreate it with the correct environment variable.`
In Docker, you can set the environment variable on an image with an `ENV` command in the Dockerfile. You can also configure the default environment used to start the container when you call `docker run -e ...`