# ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified on MAC Big Sur

Tags: sql, oracle

So I've been trying to install oracle sql 19c on my mac.
But I got stuck at probably (and hopefully) the last stage.

The message states that 'ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified'
and I know that it's something to do with the sid but can't find the right solution for me.

[image: 1]

Comment: what operating system is the container running?

Comment: The operating system is Big Sur

Comment: Oracle server isn't compatible/certified with Mac. The recommended approach is to run an Oracle Linux VM in VirtualBox and run Oracle server software on the VM.

Comment: Probably your ORACLE_SID environment variable is not set. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798861/oracle-on-docker-ora-12162-tnsnet-service-name-is-incorrectly-specified)

Comment: docker exec -it oracle "sqlplus / as sysdba"